# React-select - can't stopPropagation on valueRenderer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-select

I am trying to display a popover on click over a react-select selected value element as follow : 
[image: expected result]

My issue happens when I click on the popover trigger, the dropdown opens and the popover too... I just want to open the popover, I tried `e.nativeElement.stopPropagation`, `e.stopPropagation`, `e.preventDefault` and so on without success. Here is a sandbox If you want to know how I did this and how to reproduce the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pjv7vmlv3j

Thanks for you help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Select onClick on multi tag prevent open dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159086/react-select-onclick-on-multi-tag-prevent-open-dropdown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found a way to cancel the event. I just add an `onValueClick` prop to the `<Select />` and put the `stopPropagation` there!

Comment: Yes, this also worked for me but the content was inserted into extra `<a>` element and that broke my CSS :(

Answer (score 10):

The react-select opens the dropdown as a reaction to `onMouseDown` event, not `onClick` and that's why any `onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` can't prevent to open the dropdown. You need to add `onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` along with the `onClick` handler to open only the popover.

In [your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/61334pnr8z) the snippet below should do the trick:

```
    <span onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()} style={styles.root}>
      <span style={styles.label}>{label}</span>
      <OverlayTrigger
        trigger="click"
        rootClose
        placement="bottom"
        overlay={popover}
        animation={false}
      >
        <span style={styles.trigger}>{`${selected} / ${contacts.length}`}</span>
      </OverlayTrigger>
    </span>
```