# React-Select onClick on multi tag prevent open dropdown

Tags: javascript, react-select

I'm using a fork of React-Select for a project adding customized functionality. I'm trying to disable the dropdown from opening when a user clicks on one of the tags (When multi is set to true). So if a user clicks on one of the tags the dropdown menu won't open. I went over Value.js file to see if I could find the isOpen state triggered by clicking on the tags but couldn't find it.

Here's a screenshot illustrating what I mean.
[image]

Comment: There is an issue with [openOnClick=false](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2014), but you can try  something similar to hide the menu...

Comment: Check this [issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1989), about how to open the `dropdown` menu

Comment: Ok - Thanks @btzr will check this out now.

Answer (score 3):

In case if used custom tag component (`valueComponent`)
try to use:

`onMouseDown = (e) => e.stopPropagation();`

(instead of `onClick`) on that component.