# react-select: stopPropagation when clicking on an option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a react-select wrapped in a parent component. The parent has its own `onClick` which shouldn't fire when an option from the dropdown menu is clicked. However it should fire when the dropdown control is clicked and the menu expanded.

Due to [how react-select is designed](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1631), the `onChange` prop doesn't actually pass the event, as there is a lack of reliable events for `onChange`.

I tried wrapping the select in another component with `onClick={(e)=>e.stopPropagation}`, but that stops the parent `onClick` from firing all together, while I only want to stop propagating when an option is clicked.

I guess another way of asking this question would be how to differentiate dropdown control click and menu option click in react-select. (and still, how to get the underlying event to be able to call `event.stopPropagation`)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393999/react-select-cant-stoppropagation-on-valuerenderer-component)'s a similar question but the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: Recently I had to replace the input for react select. So I think a possible option is to replace the option component with `stopPropagation` onClick.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const stopPropagation = (e: React.MouseEvent) => e.stopPropagation();

const MenuPortal = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <components.MenuPortal {...props}>
    <div onClick={stopPropagation}>{children}</div>
  </components.MenuPortal>
);

export const ReactSelect = (props: CustomSelectProps) => {
  return (
    <Select
      {...props}
      menuPortalTarget={document.body}
      components={{ MenuPortal }}
      styles={{ menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).